# Is Wake On LAN over WiFi possible?

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, wake-on-lan

My PC is connected to my router via ethernet.

When I boot up my PC, I want to automatically wake up my laptop that'll be in another room.

My laptop is connected wirelessly to my router.

Both PC and laptop are on Windows 10.

I've enabled Wake On LAN in my laptop's BIOS.

In my laptop's WiFi adapter settings, I've enabled these settings:

- Wake on Magic Packet
- Allow this device to wake the computer
- Only allow a magic packet to wake the computer

So it looks like it's possible, but I'm stuck on how to send the magic packet.

I tried TeamViewer, realising after all the configuration steps that TeamViewer requires the target machine to  be connected to my router via ethernet cable.

Is there any other way of making this work?

Comment: It might help if you would include your OS, so that we can suggest you a simple solution

Answer (score 4):

I abandoned Wake On LAN over WiFi and achieved it with powerline ethernet adapters.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is certainly possible.

1. Enable wake on magic packet in your wifi network adapter settings
   [image]
2. On Windows install the utility called wolcmd from here, https://www.depicus.com/wake-on-lan/wake-on-lan-cmd

On Mac, install the utility wakeonlan from brew, and if you don't have brew install the brew package manager from here, https://brew.sh/

`brew install wakeonlan`

3. Find the mac address of the computer you want to wake up,

[image]

On Windows run,

`wolcmd [mac address] [ip address] [subnet mask] [port number]`

On Mac run,

`wakeonlan [mac address]`

Comment: Any idea how to do so on Linux?

Comment: @RokeJulianLockhart For RedHat Linux you can use command "wol [mac address]"

Answer (score 0):

I looked on https://www.depicus.com/wake-on-lan/wake-on-lan-cmd and saw this link to a Repo with the Linux version : https://github.com/Depicus/WoLF

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).